# Count elements in an array from a document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, count

I am trying to set up a blog, where each post contains multiple paragraphs. I would simply like to count the number of paragraphs in a particular post. In the "Blog" collection, my documents (=posts) are as follow :

```
{ id : String
  title : String
  paragraphs : [ { position: Int, body: String } ] }
```

I would like a function returning an Integer. Maybe something close to :

```
var NumberParagraphs = Blog.find( {id: id} ).paragraphs.length
```

(obviously this doesn't work ! ) ... Could you advise me which way to investigate? while searching the net, I am getting confused between use case for `.count()` , `$size`, or `.aggregate`

Answer (score 2):

The [`.find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find) method does not return a single document. So you either want to loop those documents as an array:

```js
Blog.find({ id: id }).fetch().forEach(function(doc) {
     var NumParagraphs = doc.paragraphs.length;
     // Then do something useful
})
```

Or just [`.findOne()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-findOne) for a single document:

```js
var doc = Blog.findOne({ id: id });
var NumParagraphs = doc.paragraphs.length;
```

The same principles apply to the raw methods for MongoDB, not just meteor.

Answer (score 1):

And an example using the aggregate method and $size, in case you were wondering:

```js
var numParagraphs = Blog.aggregate([
    {
        $match : {
            "_id" : id
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            "pCount" : {$size : '$paragraphs'}
        }
    }
]).pCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
Blog.findOne({_id:id}).paragraphs.length
```

Thanks